# Querying custom table in WordPress to return most recent rows first

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have created a custom table which stores 'post likes' in WordPress.

```
$sql[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$table_prefix}like (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    post_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        KEY recommenders (post_id, user_id)
) {$charset_collate};";
```

When a user clicks on a 'like' button on a WordPress post, a row gets added to the table which captures the user's ID and the post ID.

To get an array of all user IDs that have 'liked' a particular post I can do this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM {$table_prefix}like WHERE post_id = %d", $post_id ) );
```

I'd now like to do 2 things:

1. How can modify my query so that most recent rows added to the table are returned first in the `$result` array?
2. How can I do exactly the same as question 1 but return 5 rows only?

Comment: 1. order by id desc? 2. limit 4 (0 based)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: You can order them by your `id` in descending order by adding `` ORDER BY `id` DESC `` to the query.

For 2: Add `LIMIT 0, 5` aswell:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT `user_id` FROM `{$table_prefix}like` WHERE `post_id` = %d ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 5", $post_id ) );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Just wondering why `LIMIT 0, 5` and not just `LIMIT 5`?

Comment: Just used to the `LIMIT x, y` syntax. It lets you specify a start-offset by using `x`. (Useful when building something like "Show 20 results beginning an page 10")

Answer (score 0):

1. To ensure the `ORDER BY` as ccKep alluded to I would add a LikeDate Column to your Table as a DateTime(TimeStamp)and then use the `ORDER BY` on the LikeDate Column.  This ensures that you count the return visitors, who may REALLY LIKE the post.
2. See the [FOUND_ROWS Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), in case you want to know the total that would have been returned without the limit

Comment: 1 < That would be an enhancement to my table. Was thinking about doing this actually. Thanks for the idea